# Laravel 5.7 session flush message is shown many times, although it should appear only once

Tags: php, laravel

Faced a problem) As far as I know, Session::flash(...) should be recorded in a session for only one show, but it does not disappear for me, when I update the page, I always have it.

Here is an example code:

```
public function update(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'amount' => 'required|integer'
    ]);

    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->balance += $request->amount;
    $user->save();

    Session::flash('success', "Balance updated");

    return redirect('/balance');
}
```

The message is displayed like this

```
@if(Session::has('success'))
   <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
      {{ Session::get('success') }}
   </div>
@endif

@if(Session::has('error'))
   <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
      {{ Session::get('error') }}
   </div>
@endif
```

Help, please, I can not understand what the problem is. I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, i hope help you

```
public function update(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'amount' => 'required|integer'
    ]);

    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->balance += $request->amount;
    $user->save();

    return redirect('/balance')->with('success', 'Balance updated');
}


@if (session('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('success') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

for more info please check document :

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data
and 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session#flash-data

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The same situation, the message does not disappear after updating the page (

Comment: @ArtemMosakovskiy cloud you please share your route?

Comment: solved the problem)) at the end of the template there was a call to the function exit(); which stopped the application, apparently through this the variable was not removed from Session